# "use to refer to" vs "use for referring"

Tags: grammar

*Okaasan* and *haha* are words for *mother* in Japanese.

Which one should I **use for referring to my mother?**

Or

Which one should I **use to refer to my mother?**

A grammar app told me the second one is correct, but I can't understand why.

Comment: I suspect because the second one is idiomatic, the app says it's the correct one. First one does indeed sound clunky, although I don't see anything grammatically wrong with it.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical and equivalent in meaning, and there's no reason to be verbose here, so the more concise sentence is preferred.